# Use of 'substantially similar' or other phrases describing elements to be similar but not identical

Tags: claim-construction

Two icons in different parts of an interface are intended to be recognized as representing the same thing at some level, yet are also distinguished by other visual cues (size, location within interface, some graphic details) as having differences of purpose. To describe them in claims as a comparison, is there a better phrase than 'substantially similar'?

Answer (score 1):

The followings are not to be construed as legal advice or opinion.

If the **two icons** differ by look ('**visual cues**'), location ('**in different parts of an interface**') and purpose (**a thing at 'different level'**, assuming your 'some' is not the typos error for 'same'), then I believe they are neither same, nor 'substantially same'.

One suggestion is to treat those two icons as different and claim construction (example) can be as follows:

> a first icon to represent (say A) at (location) wherein the first icon
>   (mention all characteristics)...
>
> a second icon to represent (the A) at (location) wherein the second
>   icon (mention all characteristics) ...

Again I repeat the golden rule, "go to a professional (patent agent or attorney)" for reliable and best advice.

Comment: In my opinion, writing your own claims is like performing your own appendectomy. Painful and likely to fail.

Comment: If a physician's service (read patent agent/ attorney) can not be availed then a patient (patent applicant) may elect the painful path of self-surgery. I did and succeeded. For a non-attempt, non-achievement is certain; for an attempt, there is a chance and that hope is a driving force.

Comment: In my experience, obtaining a patent and obtaining a good patent are two different things.

Comment: Having achieved 3 patents where I wrote the claims (using only a few general tips and suggestions from more experienced persons), I would still concede (regrettably) that “amateur-produced“ patents like mine are, typically, rather weak and vulnerable to challenges and circumvention. If and when experienced practitioners smell the weaknesses, they will move in for the kill – if there's a clear motivation to do so.

Comment: @Charles. Agree to the fullest. Also admit that 'pro se' prosecution is never to be solicited. But, as I said, financial constraint is an insurmountable hurdle for independent 'hobbyist' inventors compelling them to (as in case of self) prefer an 'attempt' to 'non-attempt' as 'hobson's choice'.